# Run if/else script with only part of a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I am trying to edit my Javascript to pull different data via an AJAX call based upon only part of a URL. Currently, my if/else script looks like this:

```
if (window.location.href=="london") {
  $.ajax({
  url: '../financial-reports/outwork-vs-expenses-data-london.php',
  dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(item) {
      dates.push(item.date);
      expenses.push(item.expense);
      outworks.push(item.outwork);
      expensesOutworks.push(item.expensesOutwork);
      budgetedOutworks.push(item.budgetedOutwork);
      myExpensesChart.update();
      });
  });
} else {
  $.ajax({
  url: '../financial-reports/outwork-vs-expenses-data.php',
  dataType: 'json'
  }).done(function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(item) {
      dates.push(item.date);
      expenses.push(item.expense);
      outworks.push(item.outwork);
      expensesOutworks.push(item.expensesOutwork);
      budgetedOutworks.push(item.budgetedOutwork);
      myExpensesChart.update();
      });
  });
}
```

This doesn't work as currently written since `if window.location.href=="london")` is only part of the URL, not the full URL. Is there a way to edit this script to run only based off of the last bit of the page URL? For example: `/london`, `/nw`, etc.? Is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: look at the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) for the reference of String functions. Those are the functions you can call on a string, including some interesting comparison, like `endsWith`

Comment: If you have control over the url, then it's best to put in "london" as a field in the querystring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) or something like that where the value "London" is explicitly defined and can be read with confidence. Otherwise, and answer like Rahuls below is what you're stuck with using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (window.location.href=="london") {
```

Use below code

```
var URL = window.location.href;
if(URL.indexOf("london") !== -1)
```

The `.indexOf` function will find out a substring is exist or not in a string. And in your case you wants "london" is exist or not in URL.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking, when the url something like 'https://example.com/london' , so you just want to include or get the value of london. below code will help to provide always last bit of value of the url.

```
  window.location.pathname.splitOnLast('/')[1]
```

it will give you '/london'. or you can just check the existence of theondon in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it is not necessary to use if else like above

You can use like below

```
 var dataurl = document.URL

  $.ajax({
        url: 'somepage.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        data: dataurl
    });
```

in somepage.php file you can process the data however you want based on the dataurl
And also in javascript you can do like below

```
   var urlTopost="other.php";
   if(document.url.indexOf("london")!==-1)
   {
     urlTopost="london.php";
   }

   $.ajax({
    url: urlTopost,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    data: dataurl
});
```